# hibernate native query variable

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I am trying to write native query:

```
@NamedNativeQuery(name = "getUncheckedTests",
    query = "SELECT t.test_name AS test_name, q.question AS question, @counter \\:= COUNT(ua.is_checked=0) AS uncheckedAnswers FROM user_answer ua" +
            " JOIN result r on r.id = ua.result_id" +
            " JOIN test t on r.test_id = t.id" +
            " JOIN question q on ua.question_id = q.id" +
            " WHERE r.is_checked = false AND q.is_open = true AND ua.is_checked = false" +
            " AND r.test_id IN (SELECT t.id FROM result r" +
            " JOIN test t on t.id = r.test_id" +
            " JOIN user u on u.id = r.user_id" +
            " WHERE r.permission = 2 AND u.id = :userId) and r.permission = 1 and @counter > 0" +
            " GROUP BY ua.question_id")
```

However, i am getting empty result as `@counter > 0` does not work properly. I can execute this query right in Workbench, however no result if it's put in Hibernate as native query

Answer (score 0):

You should probably check the actual SQL Hibernate executes by [enabling logging of the statements](http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-display-generated-sql-to-console-show_sql-format_sql-and-use_sql_comments/) or by using [log4jdbc](https://code.google.com/archive/p/log4jdbc) and make sure you execute the query with the proper parameters.

Comment: I mean checking if Hibernate picks up the parameters etc. you expect to be used. Without that it is bit like guessing.